# Difference between Hide and Unpublish in Windows Phone Dev Center

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to remove/hide my app from the public Windows Phone Store.

In the Windows Phone Dev Center, on the app page, there are two different options:

- Hide app in Store
- Unpublish

What is the difference between these two? How should I choose, or maybe do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Hide from Store**: The app is in a *unlisted state*, this means users can't find it using built-in seach function of the Store, moreover the app won't apper in Store spotlight. Actually users are still able to download/rate it and, if search engines (Google, Bing...) indexed the Store page, users will easily reach that page.
- **Unpublish**: It really removes the app package you previously uploaded, so that new users won't be able to download it. However,
  neither this option can perform a forced uninstall of the app from
  users who have it on their phones. If they decide to uninstall it,
  they **can** reinstall as your app still appear under "My
  Apps" section of the Store.

So I would exclude the first option, usually it's used when you want to limit distribution of the app. Go with the second one, but keep in mind that old users can use the app whenever they want.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding an app only removes it from the search. Someone who knows the direct url to your app will still be able to download it. Unpublishing removes the app entirely, making it impossible to be found or downloaded.

If you unpublish the app, it'll be hidden de facto, so you don't have to do both.